# Unsafe Script on IFRAME CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm creating an Entity Form in CRM with an IFRAME.
The URL in the IFrame is a WebApp I created using asp with some Java script Function.
But every time I make a New Record on my Entity Form in CRM, the IFrame is not Loaded and a SHIELD icon appears on my address bar with an option  "Load Unsafe Script". Then the HTTPS become red.

How can I remove that Shield Icon or Automatically load my Script or make my Script safe to load?

Comment: Can you post an Image of, IFrame properties ? and which browser are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome  but when I use IE it display a dialog having an option to Load Unsafe Script or not.